# BMC Remedy Integration WSDL

Tags: integration, remedy

Is there a way to access/download the following out of the box  web services(wsdl) with the demo/trial access  provided by remedy?. Any other options?

```
http://<midtier_server>/arsys/WSDL/public/<servername>/HPD_IncidentInterface_Create_WS

http://<midtier_server>/arsys/WSDL/public/<servername>/HPD_IncidentInterface_WS_Get_Status
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is just a skeleton which tells how you should build your web service. to consume one you explicitly have to create the url with the actual server name and form names. hope this helps

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Since this WS is OOTB object, you just need to replace mid tier servername with port and arserver name in the WSDL then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

### Heading ##https://<midtier_server>/arsys/WSDL/protected/list

Here you can download

OR

http://<midtier_server>/arsys/WSDL/public//HPD_IncidentInterface_Create_WS

fill proper mid tier server with port and enter proper server name.
Load WSDL url in any browser. and Save this as xml file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).